# One Apple id on two iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, apple-id

I am using one Apple ID for two iPhones which seems to be fine,however when I download an app on one iPhone it gets downloaded on the other too. even if I upgrade an app it gets upgraded on the second iPhone as well.

How is that possible and can I disable it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably *automatic downloads* are enabled.

You can disable them in **Settings → Store** as described [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4539).